# MySQL Workbench - Cannot see results unless i have highlighted field

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench on a new computer and when I run a query, I can see the result grid, however, there are no values visible. I can only see the values when I highlight a column, as in the picture.

[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Awl.jpg)
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Workbench a couple different times, to no avail.

There's no error or anything, the query ran successfully.

Comment: Well, if you think you've found a bug in the program, maybe you should consider reporting it to them? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-reporting-bugs.html

Comment: Is that a Windows box? What version? Have you changed any theme setting in your system (like text colors)?

Comment: @MikeLischke This is Windows, the latest version (8.0.16). I have not changed any theme or settings. It's perplexing. This was a fresh install on a new machine.